# How to put data into session array in Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony5

I have two table with OneToMany relation
eg:

item

```
id|product_name|price|description
id|product xyz |12$  |blah blah
```

sizeAttriButes

```
 id: size
  1: XL
  2: XXL
```

On the product view page the size is in Dropdown.

what I want to achieve here is when I click on the add to cart I want to fetch exact size attr in Cart. In single add to cart, it works, but in multi product the size is repeating, I want to achieve the following:

```
        id|product_name|price|description|size
        1 |product xyz |12$  |blah blah  | XL
        2 |product abc |15$  |blah blah  | XXL
```

I'm doing following:

```
        $basket = $session->get('basket',[]);
        if($request->isMethod('POST')){
            $product_size = $request->get('size');
            $basket[$product->getId()] = $product;
            $session->set('basket', $basket);   
            $session->set('size', $product_size);    
        }
```

cart:

```
            {

    $basket = $session->get('basket',[]);
    $size = $session->get('size');
    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
        unset($basket[$request->request->get('id')]);
        $session->set('basket', $basket);
    }

    $price = array_sum(array_map(function($product){
       return $product->getPrice();
    },
    $basket
));

    return $this->render('cart/cart.html.twig',[
        'basket' => $basket,
        'price' => $price,
        'size' => $size
    ]);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DW2oL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BygfT.png)

I might be doing wrong.. Please guide me...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put arrays in session symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619779/put-arrays-in-session-symfony2)

Comment: You haven't described a problem or included any errors. Can you please tell us what happens when you run/employ your code.

Comment: @Burkely91 there is no error ,but Im lacking in logic. As said above when customer clicks on size(from dropdown) I want to display in cart product data along with size clicked by customer. In single product it working but in multiple same size is repeating.

Comment: Can you show any output then if there are no errors? It helps us solve the problem if we can see the code you've written as well as it's output.

Comment: @Burkely91 I have added the image.